# Multiple entry points not working in Symfony 4.4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have 2 user types on a website: Users and Vendors. Each of those types will use own login form. Therefore I've decided to create 2 separate firewalls in security.yaml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Main\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

        App\Entity\Main\Vendor:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        users_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Main\User
                property: email

        vendors_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Main\Vendor
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            provider: users_provider
            form_login:
                check_path: security_login
                login_path: security_login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                csrf_parameter: _csrf_token
                csrf_token_id: authenticate
                use_referer: true
                target_path_parameter: go_to

            logout:
                path: security_logout


        vendor:
            pattern: ^/vendor/
            anonymous: ~
            provider: vendors_provider
            form_login:
                check_path: security_vendor_login
                login_path: security_vendor_login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                csrf_parameter: _csrf_token
                csrf_token_id: authenticate
                use_referer: true
                target_path_parameter: go_to
            logout:
                path: security_logout

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/%locales%/login, roles: ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'] }
        - { path: ^/%locales%/vendor, roles: ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'] }
        - { path: ^/%locales%, roles: ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'] }
```

Login form for User user-login.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="{{ path('security_login') }}"
          method="POST">
        <input type="text"
               id="email-field"
               class="form-control"
               name="_username"
               value="{{ form._username.vars.value }}">

        <input type="password" id="password-field" class="form-control"
               name="_password">

        <input type="hidden" id="csrf" name="_csrf_token"
               value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Login form for Vendor vendor-login.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="{{ path('security_vendor_login') }}"
          method="POST">
        <input type="text"
               id="email-field"
               class="form-control"
               name="_username"
               value="{{ form._username.vars.value }}">

        <input type="password" id="password-field" class="form-control"
               name="_password">

        <input type="hidden" id="csrf" name="_csrf_token"
               value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Routes for login are defined in routes.yaml:

```
security_login:
    path: /login
    controller: App\Controller\Main\SecurityController:loginAction
    methods: [GET, POST]

security_vendor_login:
    path: /vendor/login
    controller: App\Controller\Main\SecurityController:vendorLoginAction
    methods: [GET, POST]
```

And the login methods in SecurityController:

```
public function userLoginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $error = $this->authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $this->authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        $form = $this->formFactory->create(LoginForm::class, [
            '_username' => $lastUsername
        ]);

        return new Response(
            $this->twigService->render(
                'main/security/user-login.html.twig',
                [
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'error' => $error,
                ]
            ),
            200
        );
    }

    public function vendorLoginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $error = $this->authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $this->authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        $form = $this->formFactory->create(LoginForm::class, [
            '_username' => $lastUsername
        ]);

        return new Response(
            $this->twigService->render(
                'main/security/vendor-login.html.twig',
                [
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'error' => $error,
                ]
            ),
            200
        );
    }
```

When I use the /login route then I'll be successfully logged in as User. However if I go to /vendor/login page and submit email and password the page just refreshes without any error messages and I'll not be authenticated.
And in var/log/dev.log I see this

```
[2020-01-23 17:12:05] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. []
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working security.yml with some comments. It is important to have the right order of the firewalls. Also using "^" in pattern definition of each firewall will break the whole functionality i.e. only the main firewall will be working. I don't want that firewalls share "context" with each other, so for me is this parameter not necessary. You can also add the custom user checker for each firewall if you want to do something during the authentication process.

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Main\User: bcrypt
        App\Entity\Main\Vendor: bcrypt

    providers:
        users_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Main\User
                property: email

        vendors_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Main\Vendor
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        vendor:
            pattern: /vendor
            anonymous: ~
            provider: vendors_provider
            # Custom user checker
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html
            # user_checker: App\Service\Main\VendorChecker
            form_login:
                check_path: security_vendor_login
                login_path: security_vendor_login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                csrf_parameter: _csrf_token
                csrf_token_id: authenticate
                use_referer: true
                target_path_parameter: go_to
            logout:
                path: security_vendor_logout
                target: /vendor
            remember_me:
                secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
                lifetime: 1209600 # 2 weeks in seconds
                path:     /
                httponly: true
                # Enable if you want that if you're authenticated in one firewall, you're automatically authenticated in another too
                # Just use random but the same name in all firewalls you want to share the context with
                # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context
                # context: my_context

        main:
            pattern:   /
            anonymous: ~
            provider: users_provider
            # Custom user checker
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html
            # user_checker: App\Service\Main\UserChecker
            form_login:
                check_path: security_login
                login_path: security_login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                csrf_parameter: _csrf_token
                csrf_token_id: authenticate
                use_referer: true
                target_path_parameter: go_to
            logout:
                path: security_logout
                target: /
            remember_me:
                secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
                lifetime: 1209600 # 2 weeks in seconds
                path:     /
                httponly: true
                # Enable if you want that if you're authenticated in one firewall, you're automatically authenticated in another too
                # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context
                # context: my_context

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/vendor/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        # Add your access control rules
```